# NetworkOnMainThreadException even with AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I got this fault while trying to implement network handling in an app that i'm making. I have looked around and not found anything that i feel really applies to my situation. I have created a static class where i handle all networking, so i can call on the methods in the class directly, without creating an instance. Here is the code that got me the error. The string-variable "input" is a static field in the class.

```
private static void getJsonInput(final String url){
    new AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String tempInput = "";
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
            try {
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                tempInput = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return tempInput;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String tempInput) {
            super.onPostExecute(tempInput);
            input = tempInput;
        }
    };
}
```

This is the only part of my app where I use network handling. Does anyone know why this is happening to me?

i call that method from this method in the same class:

```
public static ArrayList<String> getOptions(String url){
    ArrayList<String> options = new ArrayList<>();
    getJsonInput(url);
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(input);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("grupper");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            options.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return options;
}
```

Here is my stack trace:

```
03-06 11:12:11.005    1986-1986/com.example.daniel.androidlab3 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.daniel.androidlab3, PID: 1986
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.daniel.androidlab3/com.example.daniel.androidlab3.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
            at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
            at com.example.daniel.androidlab3.NetworkHandling.getJsonInput(NetworkHandling.java:41)
            at com.example.daniel.androidlab3.NetworkHandling.getOptions(NetworkHandling.java:23)
            at com.example.daniel.androidlab3.MainFragment.onCreateView(MainFragment.java:36)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2053)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:894)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:833)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1452)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5948)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

This is the line in my MainFragment that I call the methods from:

```
    ArrayList<String> options = NetworkHandling.getOptions("http://tddd80-afteach.rhcloud.com/api/groups");
```

Comment: This is not the code that causes the exception. You're not even executing the asynctask. See the stacktrace to learn where the main thread network access is.

Comment: i call that method from this method in the same class:    'code' public static ArrayList<String> getOptions(String url){
        ArrayList<String> options = new ArrayList<>();
        getJsonInput(url);
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(input);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("grupper");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                options.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return options;
    } 'code'

Comment: The network exception isnt in the code you showed us. Post the stacktrace.

Comment: posted it as an answer to the question

Comment: The `AsyncTask` is never executed. But even worse, your code will never work as expected. You call `getJsonInput()` which should start a background processing (but it doesn't), then your flow continues to parse something, that has yet to come (your input might not be initialized or there might be some previous value). Anyway it won't work.

Comment: @DanielProos You shouldn't post addtional information for your question as an answer. Edit your question instead, using the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28899051/edit) link below the question.

Comment: Your stack trace does not line up with your source code. The stack trace shows that `getJsonInput()` is directly calling `execute()` on an `HttpClient` instance, which is not what your code does. Either you are not running this version of the code, or you are looking at the wrong stack trace.

Comment: Im sorry for posting additional info as answers, its fixed now!

Comment: Well done in deleting those answers. Before you did so I noticed that LookUpHostByName() was causing the exception. You must have called that somewhere outside the AsyncTask. That uses the network.

Comment: I am sure this is the same version of the code that I'm running. I tried again just to be sure.

Comment: This is so weird. I definitely don't call the LookUpHostByName() method in my code and the only network handling i do is in this class and I've already posted the only two methods i have in it...

Comment: Well from your stacktrace, it's originating from here:  at com.example.daniel.androidlab3.MainFragment.onCreateView(MainFragment.java:36)

Comment: I noticed that, but the only thing I'm doing there is calling these functions. I have updated my response with this line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, finally. Apparently when a variable is given a value in the main thread from a method, it doesn't matter if the method used, in my case `NetworkHandling.getOptions()`, uses AsyncTask to temporarily open a new thread. It will still see this as using networking in the main thread.

I solved it by removing the AsyncTask from my NetworkHandling class and replacing it with a regular method that does the networking. Then in the fragment, I created a method in which i put an AsyncTask that called on the network handling methods, like so:

```
private ArrayList<String> options;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ListView listView = new ListView(getActivity());
    options = new ArrayList<>();
    getOptions();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, options);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    return listView;
}

private void getOptions(){
    new AsyncTask<Void,Void,ArrayList<String>>(){
        @Override
        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String input = NetworkHandling.getJsonInput("http://tddd80-afteach.rhcloud.com/api/groups");
            return JsonParser.getGroups(input);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> groups) {
            options.addAll(groups);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }.execute();
}
```